# Pegar o valor de um select dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Gostaria de saber como pego o valor de um `<select>` dinâmico, ou seja quando eu modificar o valor ele me apresentar este valor, imagino algo como abaixo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
varItens = document.getElementById('caminhos');

for( i = 0;i < varItens.length;i++)
{ 
  varItens.options[i].selected = true; 
   alert( varItens.options[i].id );
}
```

Porém não funciona, pois sei que isto era caso fosse estático.

Comment: Você deseja pegar o valor selecionado pelo usuário ou todos os valores do select? No seu exemplo você está tentando selecionar todos e tentando exibir o `ID` da `option`, que provavelmente será sempre `null`.

Comment: seria de cada option quando o mesmo fosse selecionado

Comment: Para fazer isso a resposta do @Danilo está correta, desde que você possa usar jquery, como está nas tags da pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vê se isso te ajuda:

```js
$("#caminhos").on('change', function(e){
  alert($(this).val())
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="caminhos">
  <option value="Elemento 1">Elemento 1</option>
  <option value="Elemento 2">Elemento 2</option>
  <option value="Elemento 3">Elemento 3</option>
  <option value="Elemento 4">Elemento 4</option>
  <option value="Elemento 5">Elemento 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, acabei recordando que por ser dinâmico era só eu passar o caminho da div e depois do option ex: $('minhaDiv').on('change','#caminhos',function()
{
});

Comment: Entao essa resposta te serviu? Muito bom :D

Comment: serviu sim, agradeço

Comment: @Danilo acho que devias juntar à resposta a delegação: `$('minhaDiv').on('change','#caminhos',function(){` que era o problema original da pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Vi que já aceitaste uma resposta com jQuery. Aqui fica uma com JavaScript nativo:

```
var items = document.getElementById('caminhos');
items.addEventListener('change', function(){
    alert(this.value); // o valor que procuras é: this.value
});
```

Se o elemento ainda não estava presente precisas delegar, isso é fácil:

```
var items = document.getElementById('minhaDiv'); // elemento presente desde inicio
items.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    if (e.target.id == 'caminhos') alert(e.target.value); // o valor que procuras é: e.target.value
});
```

Neste caso não vale a pena usar jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço da seguinte maneira cada vez que seu select for escolhido ou seja selecionado você pela o valor por uma função que é chamada no onchange ou seja quando mudar esse valor fica armazenado em uma variável.

Comment: Pode nos mostrar a sua maneira com códigos?