# Pegar valor do SELECT com JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quero pegar o valor selecionado do select e retornar na tela usando js.

**HTML:**

```
    <select name="lista" id="lista-conteudos">
        <option value="ADIÇÃO">Na adição uma quantidade é somada de outra.</option>
        <option value="SUBTRAÇÃO">Na subtração uma quantidade é retirada de outra.</option>
        <option value="MULTIPLICAÇÃO">Forma simples de se adicionar uma quantidade finita de números iguais.</option>
        <option value="DIVISÃO">Divisão é o inverso da multiplicação.</option>
        <option value="FRAÇÃO">Determinada quantidade que foi dividida em pedaços ou fragmentos iguais.</option>
        <option value="1º GRAU">O grau da incógnita é 1, isto é, o expoente da incógnita é igual a 1.</option>
        <option value="2º GRAU">Representada por ax²+bx+c=0. Os coeficientes são números reais, com a ≠ 0.</option>
        <option value="POTÊNCIAÇÃO">Usamos quando um número é multiplicado por ele mesmo várias vezes.</option>
        <option value="RADICIAÇÃO">Inversa à potenciação, assim como a divisão é o inverso da multiplicação.</option>
        <option value="RAZÃO">Relação existente entre dois valores de uma mesma grandeza.</option>
        <option value="PROPORÇÕES">Trata-se da igualdade entre razões das medidas extraídas de grandezas.</option>
        <option value="ALGARISMOS">Representar números em sistemas de numeração posicionais.</option>
        <option value="GRANDEZAS">Propriedades mensuráveis de um fenômeno, corpo ou substância.</option>
        <option value="REG. DE 3">Descobrir quantidade relativa a dois ou mais valores.</option>
        <option value="PORCENTAGEM">Medida de razão com base 100.</option>
        <option value="GEOMETRIA">Plana ou euclidiana, estuda as figuras que não possuem volume.</option>
        <option value="MEDIDAS">Medida específica de determinada grandeza física.</option>
    </select>
```

**JS: Estou fazendo assim, porém só retorna o primeiro option e os outros ao selecionar não retornam no console.log**

```
<script>
        /* LER STRING DIGITADA */
        var select = document.getElementById('lista-conteudos');
        var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log(value);
    </script>
```

Comment: Já deu uma procurada? Aqui no site mesmo, existem muitas perguntas com exemplos de JavaScript pegando o valor de uma opção selecionada, esta por exemplo é bem o que precisa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102665/75267

Comment: Procurei, porém está retornando apenas 1 valor (o Adição) e ao clicar em outros não retorna no console log, preciso que retorne qualquer 1 que eu clicar.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você seleciona um `option` em um `select` o `value` do `option` selecionado será o value da tag `select`, então você pode fazer um `addEventListener` `change`, para detectar mudanças no `select` e então pegar o seu `value`, que como já dito antes o `value` do `option` selecionado "basicamente se torna" o `value` do `select`

```js
var select = document.getElementById('lista-conteudos')

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
    console.log(select.value)
})
```

```html
   <select name="lista" id="lista-conteudos">
        <option value="ADIÇÃO">Na adição uma quantidade é somada de outra.</option>
        <option value="SUBTRAÇÃO">Na subtração uma quantidade é retirada de outra.</option>
        <option value="MULTIPLICAÇÃO">Forma simples de se adicionar uma quantidade finita de números iguais.</option>
        <option value="DIVISÃO">Divisão é o inverso da multiplicação.</option>
        <option value="FRAÇÃO">Determinada quantidade que foi dividida em pedaços ou fragmentos iguais.</option>
        <option value="1º GRAU">O grau da incógnita é 1, isto é, o expoente da incógnita é igual a 1.</option>
        <option value="2º GRAU">Representada por ax²+bx+c=0. Os coeficientes são números reais, com a ≠ 0.</option>
        <option value="POTÊNCIAÇÃO">Usamos quando um número é multiplicado por ele mesmo várias vezes.</option>
        <option value="RADICIAÇÃO">Inversa à potenciação, assim como a divisão é o inverso da multiplicação.</option>
        <option value="RAZÃO">Relação existente entre dois valores de uma mesma grandeza.</option>
        <option value="PROPORÇÕES">Trata-se da igualdade entre razões das medidas extraídas de grandezas.</option>
        <option value="ALGARISMOS">Representar números em sistemas de numeração posicionais.</option>
        <option value="GRANDEZAS">Propriedades mensuráveis de um fenômeno, corpo ou substância.</option>
        <option value="REG. DE 3">Descobrir quantidade relativa a dois ou mais valores.</option>
        <option value="PORCENTAGEM">Medida de razão com base 100.</option>
        <option value="GEOMETRIA">Plana ou euclidiana, estuda as figuras que não possuem volume.</option>
        <option value="MEDIDAS">Medida específica de determinada grandeza física.</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado !!!